# PHP form returns error even with fields in forms

Tags: php, html, css, forms

PHP code:

```
<html>
<head>
<head>
</head>
<body bgcolor="000033" text="navy">
<?php
$nume="";
$email="";
$subiect="";
if (!$nume || !$email || !$subiect)
{
?>
<h4 style="color:gray" align="center">
Eroare: Toate campurile sunt obligatorii!</h4>
<p align="center">
Corectati <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">formularul</a>
</p>
<?
}
else{
?>
<h4 style="color: green;" align="center">
Formularul introdus </h4>
<hr size="1" width="75%">
<?
$mesaj = "";
$mesaj .= "<impresie data=\"". date("d M Y, G:i");
$mesaj .= "\" client = \"" . $REMOTE_HOST . "(" . $REMOTE_ADDR . ")\">\n";
$mesaj .= "<nume email=\"" . $email . "\">" . $nume . "</nume>\n";
if ($subiect)
$mesaj .= "<text>\n" . $subiect . "\n</text>\n</subiect>\n";
mail("sitecurs18@gmail.com", "subiect", $mesaj, "from:". $email);
}
?>
<hr size="1" width="75%">
</body>
</html>
```

Form code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {background-color: 000033;
}
table {margin-top: 10px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="prelucrare.php">
<table width="800" align="center" rows="5" cols="3" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="gray" colspan="3"><font face="serif" color="000033" size="+3">Contact</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="175" height="65" align="left" valign="center"><font face="arial" color="gray"size="3"><p>Numele &#351;i prenumele:</p></font></td>
<td width="225" align="left" valign="center"><input name="nume" type="text" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="65"><font face="arial" color="gray" size="3"><p>Adresa e-mail:</p></font></td>
<td><input name="email" type="text" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="65"><font face="arial" color="gray" size="3"><p>Subiect:</p></font></td>
<td><textarea rows="6" cols="40" name="subiect"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="65" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Trimite"></td>
<td align="center"><input type="reset" value="&#350;terge"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When i submit the form it takes me straight to the error page saying I didn't fill in all the fields,I tried everything but couldn't fix it.

I've tried defining the variables for the fields as empty,but it changed nothing,and also tried changing the php tags from

Comment: `$nume="";` and yes it is empty. Don't you forget to assign value to `$nume`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read form variable and assign them to your php variable. 
You have not mentioned method type i.e get or post. By default it is get so use get to read form values like this:

```
$nume = $_GET["nume"];
$email = $_GET["email"];
$subiect = $_GET["subiect"];
```

If you want post mention `method=post` in your form & replace get with post to read values.